# Aggregate monthly data in triannual (four-month) periods in R

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate, forecasting

I' have some monthly sales data `x` and I want to aggregate it by a four-month period. When I use aggregate for a quarter data `aggregate(x, nfrequency = 4, FUN = sum)` I get a nice table with the column names `Qtr1`, `Qtr2`, `Qtr3`, `Qtr4` and the years as rownames. However, when I change the frequency to `nfrequency = 3` I get only a list with the correct values, but not the nice table. Is there a clever a way to obtain a similar table than for quarter periods but with this triannual values?

[Data:](https://github.com/Joseperles/Statistical-questions/blob/master/aggregate/data.txt)

```
        Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec
2006 279.95 299.61 442.00 409.94 410.50 403.63 408.54 336.47 378.93 388.13 319.38 377.63
2007 343.37 343.09 450.52 360.06 373.00 497.27 370.10 430.72 313.88 328.64 383.43 214.27
2008 346.37 281.68 325.14 317.50 320.07 375.60 449.38 322.88 231.23 262.45 268.53 187.59
2009 261.36 225.25 299.97 312.90 351.44 298.00 332.04 271.91 183.07 246.60 260.59 127.01
2010 175.45 164.04 313.62 320.35 323.61 344.62 271.85 284.24 230.13 232.94 192.12 112.46
2011 167.15 187.44 178.87 318.83 251.52 230.51 232.49 155.83 180.65 167.19 118.87 137.40
2012 124.81 127.35 172.95 140.92 171.47 208.92 133.56 130.90 119.06  93.34  78.76  79.08
2013  97.49  98.65 117.95 142.32 138.32 118.60 147.08  88.17  91.56 115.47 114.35 100.48
2014  79.54 100.24 120.39 147.05 175.03 114.21 167.29 113.88  94.42 110.28  99.19  65.33
2015 79.44 114.24 144.33 173.30 151.79 142.02
```

Comment: Could you please share some of your data?

Comment: Please, find the data in https://github.com/Joseperles/Statistical-questions/tree/master/aggregate/data.txt

Comment: @JosePerles It took me a while to recognize that your data `x` is of class `ts`. Unfortunately, this isn't mentioned explicitely in your Q.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found this solution.

```
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
cuatrimestre<-ifelse(cycle(data) %in% c(1:4), 1, ifelse(cycle(data) %in%    c(5:8), 2, 3))
year<-as.numeric(substring(time(data), first=1, last=4))
data.cuatrimestre<-as.data.frame(cbind(data, cuatrimestre, year))
data.por.cuatrimestres<-aggregate(data~year+cuatrimestre, data.cuatrimestre, function(x) c(sum=sum(x))) 
dcast(data.por.cuatrimestres, year~cuatrimestre, sum)
```

But, surely must be a more efficient way to do it. Somebody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`, this can be done in two lines of code:

```
library(data.table)

cm <- data.table(year = as.integer(time(x)), part = (cycle(x) - 1L) %/% 4 + 1L, x)
dcast(cm[, .(sum = sum(x)), keyby = "year,part"], year ~ part)

    year       1       2       3
 1: 2006 1431.50 1559.14 1464.07
 2: 2007 1497.04 1671.09 1240.22
 3: 2008 1270.69 1467.93  949.80
 4: 2009 1099.48 1253.39  817.27
 5: 2010  973.46 1224.32  767.65
 6: 2011  852.29  870.35  604.11
 7: 2012  566.03  644.85  370.24
 8: 2013  456.41  492.17  421.86
 9: 2014  447.22  570.41  369.22
10: 2015  511.31  293.81      NA
```

## Explanation

- The first line creates a `data.table` from the data `x` which is of class `ts`. (Unfortunately, the OP has forgotten to communicate this fact in the Q.)
- The divider `4` in computing the `part` of the year gives the number of month in the period. Change this value to `3` for quarterly results (3-month period) or `6` for half-year results (6-month period).
- The second line computes the aggregates grouped by `year` and `part` of the year and then uses dcast to transform the result from long to wide format.

## Data

In order to make this solution reproducible, the data has to be made available. Unfortunately, the OP hasn't supplied a `dput` of the data but a table which is the result of printing `x` as a `ts` object.

The (slightly modified) table is read using the versatile `fread` function included in `data.table` (development version 1.9.7 used). Then it is converted from wide to long format (`melt`) giving a vector. After some date computation and ordering a time series of class `ts` is created finally.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("year        Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec
      2006 279.95 299.61 442.00 409.94 410.50 403.63 408.54 336.47 378.93 388.13 319.38 377.63
      2007 343.37 343.09 450.52 360.06 373.00 497.27 370.10 430.72 313.88 328.64 383.43 214.27
      2008 346.37 281.68 325.14 317.50 320.07 375.60 449.38 322.88 231.23 262.45 268.53 187.59
      2009 261.36 225.25 299.97 312.90 351.44 298.00 332.04 271.91 183.07 246.60 260.59 127.01
      2010 175.45 164.04 313.62 320.35 323.61 344.62 271.85 284.24 230.13 232.94 192.12 112.46
      2011 167.15 187.44 178.87 318.83 251.52 230.51 232.49 155.83 180.65 167.19 118.87 137.40
      2012 124.81 127.35 172.95 140.92 171.47 208.92 133.56 130.90 119.06  93.34  78.76  79.08
      2013  97.49  98.65 117.95 142.32 138.32 118.60 147.08  88.17  91.56 115.47 114.35 100.48
      2014  79.54 100.24 120.39 147.05 175.03 114.21 167.29 113.88  94.42 110.28  99.19  65.33
      2015 79.44 114.24 144.33 173.30 151.79 142.02 NA NA NA NA NA NA")

mdt <- melt(dt, id.vars = "year")[, dates := lubridate::ymd(paste(year, variable, "01"))]
x <- ts(mdt[order(dates)][!is.na(value), value], start = c(2006L, 1L), frequency = 12)
```